# feature names in LogisticRegression()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to know feature names that a LogisticRegression() Model has used along with their corresponding weights in scikit-learn. I can access to weights using `coef_`, but i did not know how can pair them with their corresponding weights.

Comment: I think the model just returns the coef_ in the same order as your input features, so just print them out one by one

Comment: It's in the order of the columns by default... Also to get feature Importance from LR, take the absolute value of coefficients and apply a softmax on the same(be careful, some silver already do so in-built)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a scenario:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model.logistic import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

max_features = 100
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=max_features)#stop_words='english',)# norm = None)#)

#Simple
texts_train = ['positive sample', 'again positive', 'negative sample', 'again negative']
target_train = [1,1,0,0]
texts_test = ['negative', 'positive']
target_test = [0,1]
texts_train1 = tfidf.fit_transform(texts_train)
texts_test1 = tfidf.transform(texts_test)
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(texts_train1, target_train)
predictions = classifier.predict(texts_test1)

print('accuracy (simple):', accuracy_score(target_test, predictions))
tfidf.get_feature_names()
```

['again', 'negative', 'positive', 'sample']

```
classifier.coef_
```

array([[ 0.        , -0.56718183,  0.56718183,  0.        ]])
that makes sense!

Comment: @ keramat - does this means coefficients corresponds to the features in alphabetically sorted in ascending order?

Comment: Never mind, found the answer (same as the comments to the original post)

Answer (score 1):

We if you're using sklearn's LogisticRegression, then it's the same order as the column names appear in the training data. see below code.

```
#Train with Logistic regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
#Print model parameters - the names and coefficients are in same order
print(model.coef_)
print(X_train.columns)
```

You may also verify using another library as below

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit_model=sm.Logit(Y_train,X_train)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary2())
```